# How do I resolve this docker container error in my node and reactjs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I don't know how else to resolve this issue. I keep seeing this error after running my docker container build. When I tried to access the application from my web browser, I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/server/public/index.html'
```

It is obvious something is not getting copied. I am still learning this docker container and was following a tutorial. I have crossed checked the tutorial codes with mine, they are perfectly same. His codes worked, but mine have refused to work.

Here is my dockerfile codes:

```sh
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY client/package*.json client/
RUN npm run install-client  --only=production

COPY server/package*.json server/
RUN npm run install-server  --only=production

COPY client/ client/
RUN npm run build --prefix client

COPY server/ server/

USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start", "--prefix", "server" ]

EXPOSE 5000
```

My reactjs package.json build script:

```json
 "build": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public && react-scripts build",
```

I ran both the docker build and run code in my nasa project directory

```
Desktop\Node js master class\NASA>
```

Seems nothing is getting copied into the /app after docker build. I don't know what exactly I need to do to resolve this. Here is the error that I got again when I tried to access the application via my web browser:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/server/public/index.html'
```

Comment: How are you starting the container; what does the `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` look like?  (Is there a `docker run -v` option or Compose `volumes:` that overwrites the image's `/app` directory?)

Comment: I run the container with this code: docker run -it -p 5000:5000 kings19/nasa-project

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be the problem? This error is now 3 days old with me and it is becoming frustrating. I have gone through almost the entire google pages searching for solution

Comment: It looks like you `RUN npm run build --prefix client`, but don't do the same thing for the `server` subdirectory; do you need to do that too?  You can also try `docker run --rm -it kings19/nasa-project sh` to get an interactive debugging shell in a new container based on the image just to see what's there and what's not.

Comment: The line of code that you gave me helped me to see what is inside my container after I googled further to see how to check sub lists. I have been suspecting the issue to be from when I ran npm run build --prefix client. This calls the npm package script in my client side which does two things. Firsy, it creates a folder path in the server side called public and run client build inside it. This makes the client build files available inside the server/public path. Somehow, dockerfile is not doing this task. It is not building react build file in server/public folder. I need to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't see any answer so just in case people having the same issue, it's not working because your react build script is for windows, since you use lts-alpine(linux) you can keep the MacOS/linux cmd line:

```
"build": "BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build",
```